# How can I correct my pg connection code for PostgreSQL, NodeJS and Express JS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I have two main issues when I use postman to send this POST request. 
1. The request create the record in the database except that the username value I entered is showing null in the column in the database. Or am I supposed to join the user table that is being referenced in my query?
2. After postman sent the `POST` request, the message keep sending indefinately as if the client callback is not working. 
How can I correct my database file below so that it will show a success message once the record is created in the database? 
Better still, any idea how I can use async instead?

Please note that I am using the pg library on `PostgreSQL` and Express and `Node JS`.

**DATABASE FILE FOR CONNECTION - db/index.js**

```
const { Pool } = require('pg')

const pool = new Pool({
  user: '',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: '',
  password: '',
  port: 
})

module.exports = {
  query: (text, params, callback) => {
    const start = Date.now()
    return pool.query(text, params, (err, res) => {
      const duration = Date.now() - start
      console.log('executed query', { text, duration, rows: res.rowCount })
      callback(err, res)
    })
  },
}

getClient: (callback) => {
    pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
      const query = client.query
      // monkey patch the query method to keep track of the last query executed
      client.query = (...args) => {
        client.lastQuery = args
        return query.apply(client, args)
      }
      // set a timeout of 5 seconds, after which we will log this client's last query
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        console.error('A client has been checked out for more than 5 seconds!')
        console.error(`The last executed query on this client was: ${client.lastQuery}`)
      }, 5000)
      const release = (err) => {
        // call the actual 'done' method, returning this client to the pool
        done(err)
        // clear our timeout
        clearTimeout(timeout)
        // set the query method back to its old un-monkey-patched version
        client.query = query
      }
      callback(err, client, release)
    })
  }
```

**MY POST REQUEST SAMPLE CODE - router/routefile.js**

```
exports.addKeyword = (req, res) => {
  db.query('BEGIN', err => {
      if (shouldAbort(err)) return
      const query = 'INSERT INTO Table1 (post_type, created_on) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING id'
      db.query(query, ['value1', 'value2'], (err, res) => {
        if (shouldAbort(err)) return
        const data = {
        author: req.body.username,
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        body: req.body.body,
        category: req.body.category,
        search_volume: req.body.search_volume,
        is_deleted: req.body.is_deleted
      }
      const insertPostText = `INSERT INTO m_keyword (pid, author, title, description, body, category, search_volume, is_deleted, created_on) 
                                   VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9)`
    const insertPostValues = [res.rows[0].pid, data.username, data.title, data.description, data.body, data.category, data.search_volume, data.is_deleted, 'now()']

        db.query(insertPostText, insertPostValues, (err, res) => {
          if (shouldAbort(err)) return
          db.query('COMMIT', err => {
            if (err) {
              console.error('Error committing transaction', err.stack)
            }

          })
        })
      })
    })
  }
```